# how can I check username exists in db via a jquery keyup

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hi I'm creating a form that contains username password etc.. and I used jquery to validate the form and I want to check that the username is already present in the mysql database. if it is present then the form should not be submitted.

Here is my code so far:

```
<form id="register" name="register" action="somewhere.php" method="post" >
   <label for ="Username"> Username </label><br>
     <input type="text" class="register-control" id="Username" name="Username" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Enter Username"> <br>
     <div class="username_avail_result" id="username_avail_result"></div><br>
   <label for ="Password"> Password </label><br>
     <input type="password" class="register-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ><br><br>
   <label for ="Confirm-Password"> Confirm Password </label><br>
     <input type="password" class="register-control" id="Confirm_Password" name="Confirm_Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ><br>
   <label for="email" > Email </label><br>
     <input type ="email" class="register-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Valid Email"><br><br>
 <button type="submit" >Submit</button>

 </form>
```

And the jquery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Username').keyup(function(){ // Keyup function for check the user action in input
    var Username = $(this).val(); // Get the username textbox using $(this) or you can use directly $('#username')
    var UsernameAvailResult = $('#username_avail_result'); // Get the ID of the result where we gonna display the results
    if(Username.length > 2) { // check if greater than 2 (minimum 3)
        UsernameAvailResult.html('Loading..'); // Preloader, use can use loading animation here
        var UrlToPass = 'action=username_availability&username='+Username;
        $.ajax({ // Send the username val to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
        type : 'POST',
        data : UrlToPass,
        url  : 'checker.php',
        success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
            if(responseText == 0){
                UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="success">Number available</span>');
            }
            else if(responseText > 0){
                UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="error">Number already taken</span>');
            }
            else{
                alert('Problem with sql query');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});



$("#register").validate({


errorElement: 'div',
rules:{
"Username":{
  required: true,     
  minlength:5
},
"password":{
  required:true,
  minlength:5
},
"Confirm_Password":{
  required:true,
  equalTo: "#password"
},
"email":{
  required:true,  
}
},
messages: {
Username:{
             required: "Please provide a username",
            minlength: "Your Username must be at least 5 characters long"
},
 password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
 Confirm_Password: {
            required: "Please provide a confirm password",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            }
},
email:{
            required: "Please provide a valid email",
} 
 });  
});
</script>
```

Both work super, my doubt is how can I merge both, and also if the username is already taken the form should not submitted.

Comment: This may help http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 0):

run a query in your php file to get all users with the current email i.e.`"example@example.com"` and username i.e. `"example"` if you get any rows then it exists therefore don't add it, otherwise, add it!

```
    $_GET['email'] = $email;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    if($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) { 
        //show already registered
       //you can either return false or change the return string/array to "registered"
    } else { 
       mysql_query('INSERT INTO users ..............);
    }
```

Comment: i want to check this via jquery

Comment: 2 problems, first even if you could, it would be be a quick way to security holes. second problem sql calls need to be on server side, ie. you can't do it with jquery alone you need ajax call. You already have an ajax call, therefore add it on your php file you are already calling :)

Comment: understand my problem if the username is exists the form could be submit. and i check already the username present or not

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the username if its taken, thus causing the validation to fail

```
    success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
        if(responseText == 0){
            UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="success">Number available</span>');
        }
        else if(responseText > 0){
            UsernameAvailResult.html('<span class="error">Number already taken</span>');
            //clear username
            $('#Username').val('');
        }
        else{
            alert('Problem with sql query');
            //clear username
            $('#Username').val('');
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the username on Keyup and form submit and prevent the form submit when username exists.

```
$("#register").submit(function( event ) {
  if(usernameExists($('#Username').val()))
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#Username').keyup(function(){ 
  usernameExists($(this).val();
});
```

`usernameExists()` should have all your current validation and ajax code as in your `$('#Username').keyup(function(){ });`

Comment: can u please breifly explain

Comment: What exactly would you like to know?